# How to reconnect to a socket after server restart

Tags: sockets

I'm building an application with realtime invalidations using a socket and while I have something working, It seems to stop working once I restart my server (heartbeat not send anymore).
In the process of trying to find a cure, I realized I don't fully understand the whole concept so I decided to post several questions here:

1. Who is in-charge of the re-connection? Is it the client?
2. Do both sides (client and server) have to do something in order to support a re-connection mechanism?
3. This is a bonus question - How can I achieve socket redundancy (the ability to use more than one server). Do I have to keep all connections in a session store (redis)? How do I handle re-connections in this scenario?

I try to keep this question general but in case you're interested, my application is written in Flex and uses FlashSocket.IO to connect to my server (Tornado + Tornadio2 + tornadoredis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Who is in-charge of the re-connection? Is it the client?

Yes.

> - Do both sides (client and server) have to do something in order to support a re-connection mechanism?

The server has to do what it did in the first place: accept a connection. The client also has to do what it did in the first place: create a connection.

> - This is a bonus question - How can I achieve socket redundancy (the ability to use more than one server).

Connect to another server when the first one fails.

> Do I have to keep all connections in a session store (redis)?

No. That would just waste connections.

> How do I handle re-connections in this scenario?

The same way you handle them in any scenario. Just reconnect from the client. But if you have multiple fail-over servers you wouldn't want to reconnect to the one that just failed, you would want to create a new connection to a different member of the failover server group.

Comment: Thank you EJP for the concise answer. It does make sense ...
How does the client know when the connection has been dropped? Timeout if no heartbeat for x seconds?

Comment: @Ofir The client will get a read timeout, if you've set one, or a 'connection reset' when writing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes upon this, the easiest way to know if a socket has been closed is when send() or recv() return a 0(or -1). However, I think it is also possible to send() 0 bytes, at which point recv() could technically still return 0, but remain open.

I guess you could handle that situation, by waiting a few seconds and trying send() again. If it was indeed closed, and you try to send() data down the socket, then you will return -1. If it was zero again, then that means that the recv()ing end didn't have memory for the buffer to accept anything unto.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, the client is in the charge to detect and reconnect if required. Depending on a state shared between client and server, both may have some 'reboot' recovery procedures, for example, if client holds a lock on the server, then server should release the lock on client disconnect and client have to acquire a new lock. This is highly dependent on what your client and server do. If you want to have an distributed/clustered service, then most of above is still true. It just more complicated, as server state shared between servers and you have to synchronize it. Probably you don't want to implement this by your self and use one of existing solutions - redis, mongodb, apache-zookeeper....

Comment: Thanks tigran. I'm unfamiliar with socket locks. Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: There is no such thing as a socket lock. I can't see how this answers any of your questions. -1

Comment: @EJP nobody talks about socket locks. Any database will rollback uncommitted transactions and table locks on client disconnect.